# iOS: UIImagePickerController - using toolbar property?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, uitoolbar

Given the following code, The buttons does not show up on the toolbar. Is there something wrong?

```
UIImagePickerController* cameraPickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
cameraPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
cameraPickerController.delegate =self;
cameraPickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
cameraPickerController.toolbarHidden = NO;

UIBarButtonItem *cancelBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: self action: @selector(cancel)];
UIBarButtonItem *flexibleBarSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
flexibleBarSpace.width = 1000;
UIBarButtonItem *cameraBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera target:cameraPickerController action:@selector(takePicture)];
UIBarButtonItem *faceBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Show facemask" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: self action: @selector(showFacemask)];
cameraPickerController.toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cancelBarButtonItem,flexibleBarSpace,cameraBarButtonItem,flexibleBarSpace,faceBarButtonItem,nil];

[self presentModalViewController:cameraPickerController animated:YES];
```

Those cancelBarButtons and other should in theory show up on the toolbar. However, it does not in this case. Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not add items to the toolbar because it has not been presented yet by the `UIImagePickerController` (I think.)  Instead try this:

```
UIImagePickerController* cameraPickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
cameraPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
cameraPickerController.delegate =self;
cameraPickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;

UIToolbar *theToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 436, 320, 44)];

UIBarButtonItem *cancelBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: self action: @selector(cancel)];
UIBarButtonItem *flexibleBarSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
flexibleBarSpace.width = 1000;
UIBarButtonItem *cameraBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera target:cameraPickerController action:@selector(takePicture)];
UIBarButtonItem *faceBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Show facemask" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: self action: @selector(showFacemask)];

theToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cancelBarButtonItem, flexibleBarSpace, cameraBarButtonItem, faceBarButtonItem, nil];

[cameraPickerController setCameraOverlayView:theToolbar];

[self presentModalViewController:cameraPickerController animated:YES];
```

Basically I just created a new toolbar and set it up as the `cameraOverlayView`.

Cheers!

Comment: I have had the same idea as you as well. I did this and to my surprise, it displays an empty bar. I know the code works because other places, I use similar code and the toolBar works. I believe there is something hidden here that prevents it. Have you tried this yourself? and does it work for you?

Comment: Yes I tried this exact code and it worked for me.  The code you posted above just showed me a blank toolbar.

Comment: I did get rid of toolbarHidden=no, maybe that's it?

Comment: I just tried it again, and it does work. I'm not sure what I did before. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Late answer for the benefit of those who search and find this post.

In iOS 5 and later, the solution is to call `presentViewController:animated:completion` and set the toolbar items in the completion block.

```
    UIImagePickerController* cameraPickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    cameraPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    cameraPickerController.delegate =self;
    cameraPickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
    cameraPickerController.toolbarHidden = NO;

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: self action: @selector(cancel)];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleBarSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    flexibleBarSpace.width = 1000;
    UIBarButtonItem *cameraBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera target:cameraPickerController action:@selector(takePicture)];
    UIBarButtonItem *faceBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Show facemask" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: self action: @selector(showFacemask)];

    //cameraPickerController.toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cancelBarButtonItem,flexibleBarSpace,cameraBarButtonItem,flexibleBarSpace,faceBarButtonItem,nil];
    NSArray *tbItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cancelBarButtonItem,flexibleBarSpace,cameraBarButtonItem,flexibleBarSpace,faceBarButtonItem,nil];

    // [self presentModalViewController:cameraPickerController animated:YES];
    cameraPickerController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:^{
        cameraPickerController.toolbar.items = tbItems;
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

So i searched for similar problems and found [this](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/26348-uiimagepickercontroller-the-presentmodalviewcontroller-doesnt-work.html)

But basically his problem was that he was trying

```
[self presentModalViewController:foo animated:YES];
```

and the fix was

```
[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:camera animated:YES];
```

See if this fixes yours as well.  It hard to say for sure without seeing more code

Comment: Sorry that does not fix it. I am not using TabbarController at all.